# Application is in foreground from android service

Tags: android

I am working on a small POC on which a service broad cast a message from a worker thread in my service. But i want to make some changes like if activity is not in foreground then worker thread in my service should send a notification.
My approach, i set a static variable of my service class true onResume() of activity and set the variable false onPause() of activity. But when i debug the code i found the variable always have the default value.

Can anybody tell me where is the problem and is this approach is correct?
Or if there is any other solution to know activity is in foreground?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use sharePrefrence and set true in onStart and false in onStop method.